# how to resize a page in Tkinter when we have already given the geometric dimensions

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

am new to Tkinter programming and have written this code.
What i want is, when i click on Start conversation a new page i.e. "Conversation" should be displayed and window should get resized to another geometric coordinates. I have given the geometric coordinates in the topmost class "pythonApp" but am unable to geometric coordinates to resize the windows in other class like "Conversation" page. Can you please tell me how can i resize the "Conversation" page.
Below is my code. 
`
import Tkinter as tk
    from Tkinter import Label ,BOTH
    import time
    from PIL import Image
    from PIL import ImageTk
    import ttk
    from wx import Bottom
    import datetime as dt
    LARGE_FONT = ("Verdana",12)

```
class pythonApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.geometry("700x500")
        tk.Tk.iconbitmap(self, default="accenture.ico")                 #this is for changing the title bar image
        tk.Tk.wm_title(self,"Avatar")                                   #setting up the title
        ##now creating a container which is going to contain everything
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top",fill="both",expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)

        #creating a dictionary which willl contain frames so that when we click on Start Conversation a new frame will be loaded
        self.frames = {}

        #this will loop  over every page
        for F in (StartPage, PageOne,Conversation):
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame

            frame.grid(row=0, column = 0 , sticky ="nsew")
        self.show_frame(StartPage)

#this function will show the frame that we need
    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()# this function brings the page to the front
###################################################section for time elasped module


class ElapsedTimeClock(Label):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        Label.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.lastTime = ""
        t = time.localtime()
        self.zeroTime = dt.timedelta(hours=t[3], minutes=t[4], seconds=t[5])
        self.tick()

    def tick(self):
        # get the current local time from the PC
        now = dt.datetime(1, 1, 1).now()
        elapsedTime = now - self.zeroTime
        time2 = elapsedTime.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
        # if time string has changed, update it
        if time2 != self.lastTime:
            self.lastTime = time2
            self.config(text=time2)
        # calls itself every 200 milliseconds
        # to update the time display as needed
        # could use >200 ms, but display gets jerky
        self.after(200, self.tick)

####################################end of time elasped module
########This is the 1st page which
class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text = "Welcome",font= "LARGE_FONT")
        label.pack(pady=10, padx=10)
        photo = tk.PhotoImage(file = "howcanihelp.gif")
        w = Label(self, image=photo)
        w.photo = photo
        w.pack()
        ###########start button$$$$4
        conversationbutton = tk.Button(self, text='Start Conversation', height=2, width=40, bg="navy blue", fg="white",
                                    font=("Arial", 10, "bold"),command=lambda:controller.show_frame(Conversation))
        conversationbutton.pack(padx=7, pady=7)


        chatbutton = tk.Button(self, text='Chat', height=2, width=40, bg="navy blue", fg="white",
                            font=("Arial", 10, "bold"),command=lambda:controller.show_frame(PageOne))
        chatbutton.pack(padx=7, pady=7)
        '''stopbutton = tk.Button(self, text='Stop', height=2, width=40, fg="white", bg="navy blue",
                            font=("Arial", 10, "bold"))
        stopbutton.pack(padx=7, pady=7)'''

##################################secound page for chat window
class PageOne(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        #label = tk.Label(self, text = "Chat Page",font= "LARGE_FONT").place()
        #label.pack(pady=10, padx=10)
        clock = ElapsedTimeClock(self, font=('times', 20, 'bold')).place(x=475,y=350)
        #clock.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
        #clock.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
        photo = tk.PhotoImage(file="agent.gif")
        w = Label(self, image=photo)
        w.photo = photo
        w.place(x=435,y=50)

        #w.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
        ChatLog = tk.Text(self, bd=0, bg="white", height="8", width="50", font="Arial", )
        # ChatLog.insert(END, "Connecting to your partner..\n")
        ChatLog.config(state=tk.DISABLED)

        # Bind a scrollbar to the Chat window
        scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(self, command=ChatLog.yview, cursor="heart")
        ChatLog['yscrollcommand'] = scrollbar.set

        # Create the Button to send message
        SendButton = tk.Button(self, font=30, text="Send", width="12", height=5, bd=0, bg="#FFBF00",
                            activebackground="#FACC2E")

        # SendButton = Button(base, font=30, text="Send", width="12", height=5,
        #                   bd=0, bg="#FFBF00", activebackground="#FACC2E")
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Chat").pack()

        def DisableEntry(event):
            EntryBox.config(state=tk.DISABLED)

        def PressAction(event):
            EntryBox.config(state=tk.NORMAL)
            # ClickAction()

        # Create the box to enter message
        EntryBox = tk.Text(self, bd=0, bg="white", width="29", height="5", font="Arial")
        EntryBox.bind("<Return>", DisableEntry)
        EntryBox.bind("<KeyRelease-Return>", PressAction)

        # Place all components on the screen
        scrollbar.place(x=376, y=6, height=386)
        ChatLog.place(x=6, y=6, height=386, width=370)
        EntryBox.place(x=128, y=401, height=90, width=265)
        SendButton.place(x=6, y=401, height=90)



        stopbutton1 = tk.Button(self, text='Stop', height=2, width=40, fg="white", bg="navy blue",
                               font=("Arial", 10, "bold"),command=lambda:controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        #stopbutton1.pack(padx=7, pady=7)
        stopbutton1.place(x=399,y=401)

############################################end of chat page

class Conversation(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text = "Welcome",font= "LARGE_FONT")
        label.grid(row=0, column=1 , columnspan=3)
        photo = tk.PhotoImage(file = "agent.gif")
        w = Label(self, image=photo)
        w.photo = photo
        #w.pack(side = tk.RIGHT)
        w.grid(row=2,column=130 ,rowspan=3,columnspan=3,)
        clock = ElapsedTimeClock(self, font=('times', 20, 'bold'))
        #clock.pack()
        clock.grid(row=3,column=3)
        ###########start button$$$$4
        stopbutton1 = tk.Button(self, text='Stop', height=2, width=40, fg="white", bg="navy blue",
                                font=("Arial", 10, "bold"), command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        #stopbutton1.pack(padx=7, pady=7)
        #stopbutton1.grid(row=4,column=3)
app = pythonApp()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please read http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. I don't think you need all that code to reproduce this problem.

Answer (score 0):

windowname.geometry("newsizexnewsize")